# Is there a pseudocolumn in Hive/Presto to get the "last modified" timestamp of a given file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, presto, amazon-athena

I have an external table in Athena linked to a folder in S3. There are some pseudocolumns in Presto that allows me to get some metadata information about the the files sitting in that folder (for example, the $path pseudocolumn).

I wonder if there is a pseudocolumn where I can get the last modified timestamp of a file in S3 by using a query in AWS Athena.

Comment: I am also looking for this feature

Answer (score 4):

Trino has the `$file_modified_time` [metadata column](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#metadata-columns) for the Hive connector. You can query it like this:

```
SELECT *, "$path", "$file_size", "$file_modified_time"
FROM example.web.page_views;
```

Comment: I'm unsure if this is available now, seems like there was a PR that was merged but still not working for me in Athena =/

Comment: Is this still an issue pending to be solved?

Comment: This is supported now. I updated the answer to explain the feature.